# Programmatically close storyboard window

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, window

How to close a storyboard window programmatically.
The app is a macOS app (Cocoa, Objective-C).

`[_MainWindow close];` which I used before in .xib files doesn't work.

**Solution by Pat_Morita**
`[self.secondView.window close];`

Comment: You need a reference to the window. Then close it?

Comment: Or from inside a viewController do [self.view.window close]

Comment: Or get a reference to the window controller and call `-close` on that.

Comment: @Pat_Morita thank you very much! This was the answer.